# R Shiny - upload csv, calculate values in table, and then download results as a new csv

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny app that will allow users to upload their own data as a csv, perform some basic calculations, and then export the raw + calculated data as a csv. I am able to get the calculations showing in a table within the app, but I can't get the data to download correctly. When I try to download the raw + calculated data, it just downloads the raw data. Below is the code I have for the ui and server. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Whole-rock anhydrous conversion"),

    # Upload csv file 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput(
                inputId = "csvFile",
                label = "Upload csv file",
                accept = c(".csv")
            ),
            
            downloadButton("download", "Download anhydrous data")
            
        ),

        mainPanel(
            
            tableOutput("modifiedData")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic to calculate anhydrous concentrations
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    rawData <- eventReactive(input$csvFile, {read.csv(input$csvFile$datapath)})
    
    output$modifiedData <- renderTable({rawData() %>%
    
            
            # Calculate anhydrous concentrations
            
            mutate(LOI_Factor = Total/(Total-LOI)) %>%
            
            mutate(Anhydrous = "") %>%
            mutate(SiO2_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
            mutate(TiO2_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
            mutate(Al2O3_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
            mutate(Fe2O3_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
            mutate(MnO_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
            mutate(MgO_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
            mutate(CaO_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
            mutate(Na2O_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
            mutate(K2O_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
            mutate(Cr2O3_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
            mutate(P2O5_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
            mutate(SrO_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
            mutate(BaO_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO)))
        
        })
    
    output$download <- downloadHandler(
      
        filename = function() {paste("Anhydrous_data.csv",  Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")},
        content = function(file){
            write.csv(rawData(), file, row.names = FALSE)
            
        }
        
    )
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Move your data wrangling to the `eventReactive` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  rawData <- eventReactive(input$csvFile, {
    req(input$csvFile)
    df <- read.csv(input$csvFile$datapath)
    mydf <- df %>% 
      # Calculate anhydrous concentrations
      
      mutate(LOI_Factor = Total/(Total-LOI)) %>%
      
      mutate(Anhydrous = "") %>%
      mutate(SiO2_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
      mutate(TiO2_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
      mutate(Al2O3_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
      mutate(Fe2O3_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
      mutate(MnO_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
      mutate(MgO_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
      mutate(CaO_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
      mutate(Na2O_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
      mutate(K2O_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
      mutate(Cr2O3_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
      mutate(P2O5_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
      mutate(SrO_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO))) %>%
      mutate(BaO_anh = SiO2 * (100/ (SiO2 + TiO2 + Al2O3 + Fe2O3 + MnO + MgO + CaO + Na2O + K2O + Cr2O3 + P2O5 + SrO + BaO)))
    mydf
  })
  
  output$modifiedData <- renderTable({rawData() })
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    
    filename = function() {paste("Anhydrous_data.csv",  Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")},
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(rawData(), file, row.names = FALSE)
      
    }
  )
  
}
```